# Action Controller View issue trying to list all users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this simple code in my user_controller.rb file

```
  #listing all users
  def index
    @users = User.all # getting all the users!
  end
```

and the view folder i got this:

```
<!-- View for index action in user's controleer -->
<h1>All users</h1>

<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to user.name, user %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

The User.all.count returns 13.

Now the code is simple. Why do i get this error?

```
NoMethodError in Users#index 
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: based on what you've shown this should work fine - but something else is obviously at work here.  If you raise and exception in index action, "raise @users.inspect" -- do you see what you'd expect (something other than nil)?

Comment: how are you accessing the action ????

Comment: @miked where do i put that? raise @users.inspect?

Comment: right after the assignment to @users in your action.  It will throw an exception and the message of that exception will be the contents of that instance variable.

Comment: thanks all, I just runned rake db:reset, and now the page renders fine. there must have been a problem with the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your **user_controller.rb** to **users_controller.rb**.

You are calling the wrong controller with the wrong view !

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that your trying to call the **each** method on Users, but Users doesn't exist.  For some reason changing this line to:

`<% @user.each do |user| %>`

might work. Models are singular and Controllers are plural. Make sure you got it setup right.